# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\\'

Tags: python, jinja2

I am getting jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError with unexpected char '\' with below python code using Jinja2 template.

I see the issue is with using == in the template.

Code

```
OBJ['steps'][0]['elements'][1].update({'kind': "SERVER"})
op = "{% if steps[0].elements[1].kind == \"SERVER\" or steps[0].elements[1].kind == \"DAEMON\" %} SNIP {% endif %}"
template1 = Template(json.dumps(op))
payload= template1.render(steps=OBJ['steps'])
print(payload)
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rashtrapathy/jj.py", line 15, in <module>
    template1 = Template(json.dumps(op))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1031, in __new__
    return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 941, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 638, in compile
    self.handle_exception(source=source_hint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<unknown>", line 1, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\\' at 36
```

Please let me know what is wrong using == in Jinja2 template.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using == in Jinja, but I doubt that the issue is when you use the backslash.
Can u instead do this?

```
op = "{% if steps[0].elements[1].kind == 'SERVER' or steps[0].elements[1].kind == 'DAEMON' %} SNIP {% endif %}"
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but a shorter way to write this would be: `op = "{% if steps[0].elements[1].kind in ('SERVER', 'DAEMON') %} SNIP {% endif %}"`